# Prove that a greedy algorithm for finding minimum spanning tree will definitely stop

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, greedy, minimum-spanning-tree

This is an algorithm for finding a minimum spanning tree in a connected 
UN-directed  graph G=(V,E):

---

1. Initialization:  B = ∅ - The group of edges that will be built by the algorithm
2. while |B| < |V| - 1 do:

   a. choose some cut in the graph (S,V\S) which there isn't an edge e belongs to B that cross it.

   b. find the lightest edge crossing that cut.

   c. add it to the group B.
    B = B ∪ {e}.
3. return T = (V,B)

---

The meaning of cut is described in the attached image:
[Cut's meaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlnPS.png) 
the vertices s,u are in one group we can call S.

all the other vertices are in the group V\S.

so this is the meaning of (S,V\S) as a cut.
also - the edge (u,w) is a **crossing edge**
(u,v) is the **lightest crossing edge** in that specific cut. 
(s,u) **is not** a "crossing" edge

I need to prove that the algorithm will stop eventually. That |B| = |V| - 1
at some point.

I can use the following say in the proof:

'In any point of the algorithm, there exist a minimum spanning tree T=(V,Et)
of G that contains the group of edges B that were chosen by the algorithm.'

assuming I already proved that, I need to somehow show that there's is always some cut in the graph that none of his crossing edges been added to B yet.
while |B|<|V|-1 .
but I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that there is no such cut and |B| < |V| - 1. As the tree is connected, this means that all the vertices are connected by some edge in B (Because if a vertex is not connected, there will be a cut in which no edge belongs to B separating that vertex and the spanning tree)

As, |V| vertices need at least |V| - 1 edges to be connected, we infer that |B| >=  |V| - 1, thus contradicting our assumption.

Hence Proved.

Comment: What would you say be the run time of that algorithm?

Comment: The complexity depends on the implementation. You can check on the complexity of Prim's algorithm and find that it can be implemented in O(E + logV) using Fibonacci heaps but is generally implemented in O(ElogV).

Answer (score 0):

No part of this algorithm could loop forever. Every iteration of the step 2 loop increases |B| by 1. |B| will reach |V|-1 in exactly |V|-1 iterations, at which point the loop terminates.

If you're worried about step 2a not being possible, the (V, B) subgraph of G must be disconnected, because it doesn't have enough edges to be connected. We can always put some of its connected components on one side of a cut and some on the other side. (Even if step 2a were to be impossible at some point, that doesn't really sound like a non-termination condition.)

Comment: I see what you mean, the way this algorithm is describe makes it seems like in every step the group B will be incremented by 1 no matter what, though i wonder if that kind kind of answer will be accepted for me even though you are right as well.
anyway I got what I searched for from Vimarsh